# Exceeding maximum texture size when playing video with OpenGL on Android

Tags: android, video, opengl-es, textures

I am using the GL_OES_EGL_image_external extension to play a video with OpenGL. The problem is that on some devices the video dimensions are exceeding the maximum texture size of OpenGL. Is there any way how I can dynamically deal with this issue, e.g. downscale the frames on the fly or do I have to reduce the video size beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

If you are really hitting the max texture size in OpenGL ES (FWIW I believe this is about 2048x2048 with recent devices) then you could do a few things:

You could set `setVideoScalingMode(VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT)` on your `MediaPlayer`. I believe this will scale the video resoltion to the size of the `SurfaceTexture`/`Surface` that it is attached to.

You could alternatively have four videos playing and render them to seperate `TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES`'s then render these four textures seperately in GL. However that could kill your performance.

If I saw the error message and some context of the code I could maybe provide some more information.

Comment: Actually the default mode is VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT. Also I am rendering to a surface texture, so it does not have a setFixedSize() method. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe the way you set the SurfaceTexture size is via setDefaultBufferSize(int width, int height). It would help to see how you set up your SurfaceTexture, but I do: mSurface = new SurfaceTexture(textureID);...mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mSurface);(I am using the camera instead of the MediaPlayer)

Comment: I will try this. According to the doc, setDefaultBufferSize will be overwritten by image creators such as the camera, so I will have to test if this works. What I do is the following:

SurfaceTexture texture = new SurfaceTexture(mTextureId);
Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
surface.release();